# If $R$ is regular, is the quotient ring $R[x]/K[x]$ always Artinian or Noetherian?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be an Artinian regular ring with unity.   We say that $a\in R$ is regular if $a=axa$ for some some $x\in R$.  $R$ is regular if every element of $R$ is regular.  Let  $R[x]$ be the ring of polynomials in an indeterminate $x$ and consider the ideal $K[x]$ of  $R[x]$.

Question: Is the quotient ring $R[x]/K[x]$

(1) a Noetherian ring?

(2) an Artinian ring?

Comment: What is $K$ here?

Comment: First of all, upper case serve as much more acceptable and traditional notation for polynomial indeterminates, so we should speak of $R[X]$ rather than $R[x]$; second, when saying that $K[X]$ is an ideal of $R[X]$ that would only make sense if $K$ were an ideal in $R$ and $K[X]$ its extension to $R[X]$.

Comment: Here $K\subseteq R$.

Comment: @mariam: even better to say $K \in \mathscr{Id}(R)$ (the latter is my notation for the set of all ideals in $R$). Then you will have $R[X]/K[X] \approx (R/K)[X]$; since quotients of regular rings are regular, you have reduced your problem to inquiring whether under the assumption that $A$ is commutative regular it follows that $A[X]$ is either artinian or noetherian. And I don't see why it should have to be in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well let's take a simple case of what (I guess) you are asking, and suppose $K\lhd R$.  (You have already required $K\subseteq R$ and I don't know what else you could mean by $K[x]$ other than the polynomials with coefficients in $K$.)

Then $R[x]/K[x]\cong (R/K)[x]$, which is *never* Artinian when $R/K$ is nonzero. This should be obvious: in a polynomial ring over one variable, $(x)\supsetneq (x^2)\supseteq (x^3)\supseteq\cdots$.

Moreover, if we take $R$ to be a von Neumann regular ring such that $R/K$ is non-Noetherian, it should be obvious $(R/K)[x]$ is not Noetherian:  any strictly ascending chain $A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq A_3\subseteq \cdots$ immediately gives a chain $A_1[x]\subseteq A_2[x]\subseteq A_3[x]\subseteq\cdots$ in $(R/K)[x]$.